# MySQL Module for Python

Tags: python, sql, mysql, module

What is a good, and easy to install MySQL module for Python? Especially for Mac OS X (in terms of installation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider to install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=mysql), it will save time for this case and in the future.
Installing py-mysql is a matter of:

```
sudo port install py-mysql
```

Comment: Hmm, actually, kind of unrelated to this question, pymysql seems to have a bug with selecting more than one row. 

http://code.google.com/p/pymysql/issues/detail?id=6

Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: @Yakattak please, post another question.